# Python: string in string check fails

Tags: python, string, compare

I've been banging my head against this for hours, researching and refactoring, but I cannot get it to work.

```
import paramiko
import sys
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(switch, username='user', 
    password='pass')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("show interfaces descriptions")
line = stdout.readline()
while line != "":
    if ("UNIT " + unit) in line:
        switchPort = line [:9]
        switchPort.strip()
    line = stdout.readline()
print (switchPort)
command = "show vlans"
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
line = stdout.readline()
while line != "":       
    if acronym + "-s" in line or acronym + "-r" in line or ("subscribed" in line and "un" not in line and "pvlan" not in line):
        line.strip(' ')
        subscribedVlan = ''.join([i for i in line if i.isdigit()])
        line=stdout.readline()
        if switchPort in line:
            portVlan = "Subscribed"

    elif "un" in line and "pvlan" not in line:
        unsubscribedVlan = ''.join([i for i in line if i.isdigit()])
        if switchPort in line:
            portVlan = "Unsubscribed"
        else:
            line=stdout.readline()
            print ("SwitchPort: " + switchPort)
            print ("line: " + line)
            if switchPort in line:
                portVlan = "Unsubscribed"
                print ("In Unsubscribed")
            else:
                print("Check Failed")
```

The output:

SwitchPort: ge-0/0/3 
line:                        ge-0/0/3.0*, ge-0/0/47.0, ge-0/1/3.0*

Check Failed

The main part that I am having issues with failing is in the elif portion. I had it matching the if in syntax and logic, almost exactly, except for the other instances. What is throwing me for a loop is that switchPort printed matches a piece of the string of line. Does anyone have any idea what might be tripping this up?

I tried converting both variables to strings before the check, and that did not work.

Comment: `stdout.readline()`?

Comment: There is a `<br>` in `SwitchPort` but not in `line`.

Comment: Sometimes there are small differences between strings that can't easily be seen in the console. Try `print('SwitchPort: {!r}'.format(switchPort))` and `print('line: {!r}'.format(line))`. It may make the difference easier to spot.

Comment: Also, it may help if you provide your *exact* input

Comment: In particular, a common issue is that there's a space or newline at the beginning or end of a string that can't be spotted in the output of the program. You could also use `repr(switchPort)` and `repr(line)` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Added the rest of my code in the beginning, at least what seems relevant. Sorry, just trying to make sure nothing useless to the issue gets in. There's quite a bit of code.

Comment: Perfect! The formats brought out a space on the end of switchPort that I thought I stripped out with switchPort.strip(), but had to change it to switchPort=switchPort.strip(). Now is there any way to mark a best answer off of a comment?

Comment: @FiyaFly I copied my comment down to an answer. I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: You should take a look at the [mcve] concept. You probably didn't need *all* of the extra code there - just a small enough example to exhibit the behavior. In your case, hard coding a list of strings would probably have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there are small differences between strings that can't easily be seen in the console. Try this:

```
print('SwitchPort: {!r}'.format(switchPort))
print('line: {!r}'.format(line))
```

It will likely make the difference easier to spot.

Per discussion above, the actual issue here was a trailing space. The fix is to change:

```
switchPort.strip()
```

to

```
switchPort = switchPort.strip()
```

(`str.strip` doesn't modify anything; it returns a new, stripped, string.)